# svn export and deployment on WINDOWS

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

How to deploy the code from SVN to WINDOWS envronment?

I am looking to execute the following steps:

1. 'svn export' (only changed files after certain revisons) from WiNDOWS command line.
2. Deploy the changed files on WINDOWS environment.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @bahrep: how to deploy the code from SVN repository to WINDOWS envronment, using some script? I do not have any external tools or CI tools to do the job. I need to write a script.

Comment: Are you asking someone to write the script for you? You appear to have a handle on the tasks that need to be completed - but as you haven't defined what "deploy the changes" involves, there isn't anything anyone can do for you here.

Comment: @alroc: I would need to know the svn command line concept in windows ( sorry I am a LINUX person). I would be happy to write the script by my own. Just need to know the best approach to start with. Ok, let me clarify here I have a project in C# and during the release cycle i need to deploy the code from trunk to qa/test/prod servers. I can do it easily with LINUX (bash script). But not sure how to achieve the same in windows.

Comment: The Subversion command-line client works exactly the same as it does on Linux. Why are your developers not providing you with a deployment script for the code they've written? It's normally (in my experience) a developer's responsibility to provide anything required to compile & deploy a program into an environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a command line SVN client on Windows first. TortoiseSVN's recent versions reportedly include one. Then you need to use the same commands you did under linux. I think you actually mean 'svn co' not 'svn export' which assumes you already have checked out copies on your local file system.

Comment: As of TortoiseSVN 1.7, `svn.exe` is included in the installation by default (it can be unchecked in the install wizard).

Comment: @Amardeep: I did the same but it is not working. e.g. - I was trying to do the diff between two revisions -

%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:diff -r340:HEAD /url:svn://<my trunk>

Comment: No, don't use TortoiseProc.exe.  Use svn.exe which is also there in the same directory.

Comment: @Amardeep: I do not have svn.exe, do i need it install it seperately?

Comment: As per the comment above, any version of TortoiseSVN 1.7 and later will have it included.  Make sure you have the latest version and also make sure it wasn't excluded during installation.

Comment: @Amardeep: Just re-installed the new version and and it worked perfectly. Thaks a ton.